# How to use gnu debugger in c with a program that requires user input

Tags: c, debugging, gnu

I asked this question yesterday but everyone was saying I wasn't providing enough info, so I figured the best way to ask would be just to record myself trying to run the program so you can see what I'm doing wrong. So I deleted the old post and here is the video link: https://youtu.be/NLJ8my_UI7s

I'm reading "The C programming language" book and trying to work through the exercises. They are pretty hard so I've just been looking up the solutions online and if I can read the code and understand I've been counting it as a win. But the exercise I'm stuck on is this one

[https://penti.org/~sederlok/misc/lang/c/the_c_programming_language_-_exercises/krx116.html](https://penti.org/%7Esederlok/misc/lang/c/the_c_programming_language_-_exercises/krx116.html)

basically it's a program that takes a user input string in the console and prints out the string up to the first 20 characters and the full length of it. The challenge was to modify the main function to print out the actual length, whereas originally it only printed out the length up to the first 20 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 20

int getLine(char s[], int lim);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main(void)
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];
    char temp[MAXLINE];
    int len, max, prevmax, getmore;
    
    max = prevmax = getmore = 0;
    while((len = getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        if(line[len - 1] != '\n')
        {
            if(getmore == 0)
                copy(temp, line);
            prevmax += len;
            if(max < prevmax)
                max = prevmax;
            getmore = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(getmore == 1)
            {
                if(max < prevmax + len)
                {
                    max = prevmax + len;
                    copy(longest, temp);
                    longest[MAXLINE - 2] = '\n';
                }
                getmore = 0;
            }
            
            else if(max < len)
            {
                max = len;
                copy(longest, line);
            }
            prevmax = 0;
        }
    }
    if(max > 0)
    {
        printf("%s", longest);
        printf("len = %d\n", max);
    }

    return 0;
}

int getLine(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for(i = 0;
        i < lim - 1 && ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
        ++i)
        s[i] = c;

    if(c == '\n')
    {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    else if(c == EOF && i > 0)
    {
        /* gotta do something about no newline preceding EOF */
        s[i] = '\n'; 
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

I was having trouble understanding exactly what's going on so I tried running through it with the debugger. The problem is, normally I would run the code, and it wait for me to enter a string before continuing. When I set a breakpoint it starts running without waiting for me, and what is even more confusing, is that when I step through the part where it says c = getchar(), and I hover over c, it has been given a value of 10. I don't know where that value is coming from and I'm at a loss as to what's going on when I run this code through the debugger, and how I'm supposed to enter user input when the debugger seems to commandeer the console.

Comment: What tools are you using exactly?  gdb itself is a command-line debugger and it doesn't have any concept of "hovering over".

Comment: Note that 10 is the ASCII code for `\n`.

Comment: I'm just using the C/C++ extension and the Code Runner extension.

Comment: And what is your IDE?

Comment: I'm trying to use visual studio code with windows 10 but I think that's part of the problem. Now I'm encountering new problems like my exe file keeps getting automatically deleted so I'm going to try it in vs code on my vm with ubuntu or if that doesn't work I'll try the cs50 ide.